# Armadillo prints the imaginary part of a complex value as negative when transposed

Tags: printing, complex-numbers, armadillo

The armadillo print() method prints the imaginary value as the negative of its true value when transposing the column vector to a row vector.  Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

int
main()
{
    arma::Col<std::complex<float>> v1 = {{1.0, 1.5}, {2.0,2.5}, {3.0,3.5}, {4.0,4.5}};
    v1.t().print("v1':");
    v1.print("v1:");
}
```

Output:

```
v1':
    (+1.000e+00,-1.500e+00)    (+2.000e+00,-2.500e+00)    (+3.000e+00,-3.500e+00)    (+4.000e+00,-4.500e+00)
v1:
    (+1.000e+00,+1.500e+00)
    (+2.000e+00,+2.500e+00)
    (+3.000e+00,+3.500e+00)
    (+4.000e+00,+4.500e+00)
```

Comment: The documentation for [`trans()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#trans) says the function performs [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) which flips the signs of imaginary values. Use `strans()` instead of `trans()` to perform simple transpose.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @hbrerkere explains that the default [`trans`pose](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#trans) function is a [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) which flips the signs of imaginary values. Use `strans()` instead of `trans()` to perform simple transpose.